# WPF - Delete selected item (BitmapImage) from listview

Tags: wpf, listview, observablecollection

I have a `Listview` and for it's `ItemsSource` I have set `CollectionOfCapturedImages` (an `ObservableCollection`) ,an a `Button` for deleting selected items (`BitmapImage`) from `Listview` and also from `ObservableCollection` and a `Label` in my `MainWindow` displaying amount of captured images.

```
private void addNewImageButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CameraWindow cWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<CameraWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
    RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent);
    cWindow.manualCapture.RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
    // ListView.ScrollIntoView(ListView.Items.Count - 1);
}

public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> CollectionOfCapturedImages { get; } = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();


<ListView x:Name="ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfCapturedImages}" Height="345"  Margin="567,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Source="{Binding}" Height="150" Width="150"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

this is how I'm updating my `Label` in `MainWindow`. When I'm capturing images there is no problem, `Label`'s content is getting updated.

```
 public Action<int> amountOfCapturedImages;

this.cameraWindow = new CameraWindow(this);
 cameraWindow.amountOfCapturedImages += (int count) => {
    MwAmountOfImagesLabel.Content = count;
 };
```

and here is my delete button

```
<Button x:Name="DeleteSelectedImageButton" Click="DeleteSelectedImageButton_Click" Content="Delete Selected Image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="567,488,0,0" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145"/>
```

and this way I'm deleting `BitmapImage`s from `Listview`

```
private void DeleteSelectedImageButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CollectionOfCapturedImages.Remove((BitmapImage)ListView.SelectedItem);
}
```

but my `Label`'s content is not getting updated when I delete an image from `Listview`. How could I correctly update my `Label`'s content?

Answer (score 0):

You must remove them from the `CollectionOfCapturedImages` and bind `MwAmountOfImagesLabel => CollectionOfCapturedImages.Count`

Comment: Thanks for answer! `MainWindow`s label is getting updated when I delete images but when I capture a new image MainWindow's label continues adding images in this case from  5.

Comment: Check the count value of your collection when you capture new images...are you making a clear on the collection ? or if you create a new collection then you must notify the gui about the change

Comment: I want to remove selected item from listview (CollectionOfCapturedImages) and update label's content after I click the delete button and do the same when I capture new images. I'm not creating a new collection.

Comment: Yes, i understood. normally, the observable collection notify the gui when element are added or removed and the Count property too. in this case MwAmountOfImagesLabel is displaying the total of the collection, but you want to count only the new images ? not realy user frendly....

Comment: Could we continue discusing in a Private chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142800/discussion-between-testman-and-gcamel).

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this code:

```
cameraWindow.amountOfCapturedImages += (int count) => {
    MwAmountOfImagesLabel.Content = count;
};
```

...and simply bind the `Content` property of the `Label` the `Count` property of the `ObservableCollection`:

```
<Label Content="{Binding CollectionOfCapturedImages.Count}" />
```

You should *not* set the `Content` property of the `Label` programmatically somewhere in your code. Just set up the binding in your XAML markup.